# Calculation for one class svm

Tags: svm, mathematical-statistics

If anyone knows the calculation for one class svm, explain with a small example.
I get stucked to calculate lagrange multiplier, rbf kernel function, decision function and all...
How to calculate rho, w?
[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282545100_Malware_Detection_in_Cloud_Computing_Infrastructures]
This is my base paper. I want a example calculation for it.

Comment: This seems a little underspecified & probably too broad to be answerable. Can you clarify & narrow down your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some different approaches for that.

Suggested read : http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/